# Macbook Touchbar calling: Cannot use the keypad!

Tags: macos, iphone, macbook-pro, facetime, wifi-calling

The touchbar mac prompts for answering a call on the touchbar.

However my Google Voice callers require me to hit 1 on the keypad. The FaceTime app doesnt seem to be "connected" to the phone call. In previous macOS's there would be a little notification block looking phone call object on my screen while the call happens, this appears to have been replaced with the touchbar's functionality.

How can I type "1" so I can actually properly take my call??

I have since turned off call screening in Google Voice to mitigate this problem, but I will have no ability to handle other incoming robocalls that require me to enter numbers. Not ideal, but perhaps less critical now.

Comment: Just to confirm, you were on a call, but pressing the 1 key doesn't do anything?

Comment: It sends a 1 to whatever focused application...

Comment: INCLUDING if I focused FaceTime, which is what seems to be vaguely mediating the call.

Comment: Clarification: Focus FaceTime, Hit the 1 key on keyboard. Facetime types 1 into your FaceTime contact search field...

Comment: And to clarify, there is no floating notification block when you answer the phone via the touchbar? If you answer using the notification, does that stay there? Do you ever have this problem with outbound calls?

Comment: Notification widget for the audio call never shows up on the touchbar machine.

Comment: Does it appear when you make a phone call?

Comment: @drivec indeed it does. But not when receiving calls.